# Error: Trying to get property of non-object - twitter login

Tags: php, twitter

When you go to the [facestweet.com](http://facestweet.com) website and click on the twitter sign in button, at the top you get a

```
Notice (8): Trying to get property of non-object [APP/controllers/users_controller.php, line 220]
```

Error.

Here is the line of the code that is giving the error.

```
$this->set('redirect_url', 'http://twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=' . $requestToken->key);
```

And here is part of the code.

```
    $requestToken = $this->OauthConsumer->getRequestToken('Twitter', 'http://twitter.com/oauth/request_token');
    $this->Session->write('requestToken', $requestToken);
    $this->set('redirect_url', 'http://twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=' . $requestToken->key);
    $this->layout = 'redirect_page';
    $this->render('authorize');
}
```

}

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: is `$requestToken` this a class object..?? i think its array of configuration, you should try `$requestToken['key']`

Comment: Yay, thanks, sorry for taking so long to reply, it worked!

Comment: Due to authorize errors i had to change the code back to $requestToken->key and use ini_set("error_reporting", E_ERROR | E_WARNING | E_PARSE); to hide the errors. Thanks for the help by the way.